# logic for calculating ISO year from gregorian year and other fields

Tags: calendar, teradata

As mentioned above i need to calculate ISO year from the calendar view, 
also i have created a view on top of it for calculating ISO week number but i'm unable figure out the logic for calculating ISO year, can someone please post it as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.
kishor

structure of calendar view

```
REPLACE VIEW Sys_Calendar.CALENDAR(
```

calendar_date,
  day_of_week,
  day_of_month,
  day_of_year,
  day_of_calendar,
  weekday_of_month,
  week_of_month,
  week_of_year,
  week_of_calendar,
  month_of_quarter,
  month_of_year,
  month_of_calendar,
  quarter_of_year,
  quarter_of_calendar,
  year_of_calendar)
AS
SEL
  calendar_date,
  DayNumber_Of_Week(calendar_date),
  DayNumber_Of_Month(calendar_date),
  DayNumber_Of_Year(calendar_date),
  DayNumber_Of_Calendar(calendar_date),
  DayOccurrence_Of_Month(calendar_date),
  WeekNumber_Of_Month(calendar_date),
  WeekNumber_Of_Year(calendar_date),
  WeekNumber_Of_Calendar(calendar_date),
  MonthNumber_Of_Quarter(calendar_date),
  MonthNumber_Of_Year(calendar_date),
  month_of_calendar,
  QuarterNumber_Of_Year(calendar_date),
  quarter_of_calendar,
  YearNumber_Of_Calendar(calendar_date)
FROM Sys_Calendar.CALENDARTMP;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a fairly modern version of Teradata, you can use `TD_SYSFNLIB.YEARNUMBER_OF_CALENDAR(calendar_date,'ISO')`

If we take 2014-12-31 as an example, its ISO week is 1.  This function will correspondingly return 2015 as it's ISO year.

Comment: Just for others information I'm using 14.10.01.07 TD version